# Using R to calculate total events per day from a data frame that contains all events and their timestamps

Tags: r

I have a data frame `df` that contains 'messages'. Each row is a message. Each message has a timestamp called `df$messagedate` in POSIXct format `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`. Example:

```
> head(df)
messageid   user.id    message.date         
123         999       2011-07-17 17:54:27
456         888       2011-07-19 16:56:50
```

(Here is the `dput()`'ed version of the above):

```
df <- structure(list(messageid = c(123L, 456L), user.id = c(999L, 888L), 
      message.date = structure(c(1310950467, 1311119810), class = c("POSIXct", 
      "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("messageid", "user.id", 
      "message.date"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

How do I create a data frame with the total the number of messages per day? Example:

```
day                   message.count 
2011-07-17             1
2011-07-18             0
2011-07-19             1
```

Rather than not including the dates with no messages, I want to make sure the `message.count` is set to zero for those days.

What I have done so far: I have extracted the calendar day part of `message.date` by doing:

```
df$calendar.day<-as.POSIXct(strptime(substr(df$message.date,1,10),"%Y-%m-%d",tz="CST6CDT"))
> head(df$calendar.day)
[1] "2011-07-17 CDT" "2011-07-18 CDT" "2011-07-19 CDT"
```

And from there I can generate a list of every single calendar date in the date range:
    daterange <- seq(min(df$calendar.day), max(df$calendar.day), by="day")

Comment: If you use `dput(df)` (or perhaps dput(df[1:5, ]), you'll get a reproducible version that will help us try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a fairly straightforward solution that uses `sapply()` to count the number of messages on each date spanned by your log.

```
countMessages <- function(timeStamps) {
    Dates <- as.Date(strftime(df$message.date, "%Y-%m-%d"))
    allDates <- seq(from = min(Dates), to = max(Dates), by = "day")
    message.count <- sapply(allDates, FUN = function(X) sum(Dates == X))
    data.frame(day = allDates, message.count = message.count)
}

countMessages(df$message.date)
#          day message.count
# 1 2011-07-17             1
# 2 2011-07-18             0
# 3 2011-07-19             1
```

Comment: Thanks. This is great. Very concise. One question though, shouldn't the input parameter be the data frame (df) rather than the column (timeStamps)?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just use as.data.frame on the table() function to coerce the table results into a data frame. For instance:

```
test_data <- data.frame(date=c("March","April","April","May"),messageid=c(1,2,3,4),userid=c(55,33,1,56))
print(as.data.frame(table(test_data[1])))
```

Results in:

```
   Var1 Freq
1 April    2
2 March    1
3   May    1
```

To add in the dates that have zero messages, it strikes me that you could generate a vector of all dates that are applicable to your project (for instance, if the file covers an entire year), and then compare that vector to the data frame created by using the table statement. You just merge them together and subsequently assign 0 to those that are NA.

For instance:

```
months <- c("January","February","March","April","May","June")
full <- merge(counts,months,by=1,all=TRUE)
```

Obviously in this instance, the data frame is going to be weirdly ordered, but if you create a POSIX vector it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Whoops, I see I didn't fully address your question. I have a thought on that - editing the answer now.